# JasperReports: does positionType=''Float'' work at all for staticText?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to have a `staticText` to float below another element with variable height. I'm taking a sample from the book `JasperReports for Java Programmers`. It says that it's possible to do it. The difference with my sample is that I use a hard coded string in `textFieldExpression`, they use a $F{} field.

```xml
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="None">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="24"/>
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
    </box>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["jjjjjjjjjjj oooooooooo uuuuuuuuuu aaaaaaaaaa xxxxxxxxx u ttttt"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<staticText>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="25" width="500" height="30"/>
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
    </box>
    <textElement/>
    <text><![CDATA[ This staticText element has a positionType of "Float" ppp ]]></text>
</staticText>
```

It says that when you use `positionType="Float"`, the y attribute is ignored, because the `staticText` is positioned below the `textField`. This appears to work, BUT... is it possible they are BS'ing me? The `textField` has y=0 and height=24. The `staticText` has y=25. Coincidence? If I change the `staticText`'s y, it is obvious that it isn't ignored: the element is positioned wherever I tell it to. There's no floating!!!
Quote from the book:

`As we can see, setting the positionType attribute of <reportElement> to Float made JasperReports ignore the y position of the <staticText> element, which was pushed down by the stretched <textField> element.`

No, we don't see how it is being ignored because y=25 is where we expected it!
Does `positionType="Float"` work for `staticText` at all?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

My understanding of the floating nature is that the floating object will move down if necessary, but if the previous object is smaller than expected, it doesn't move up.

I don't recall having any problems with floating objects not actually floating down when necessary, whether they be static text or text fields.

On another note, if you find a text field works, you can use it to display static text by putting your text in quotes in the text field value (making it a Java object).

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353928/jasperreports-subreports-not-working-with-positiontypefloat#359092) applies (different elements, same situation).

One thing I didn't take right from the book's sample is that the textField's declared height (24) is less than the actual height when the element is stretched. So, y="25" on the staticText would map above its actual position; the element is actually floated down!